# Sorting JqGrid on Load

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm sorting my data on load in the jqgrid using the sortname and sortorder attributes. My problem is that it doesn't go through the onSortCol event that I've set up. onSortCol is only called when the grid is sorted by clicking on the column. Is there an event that is called before the sort happens on load?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method with reload = true, it works for me fine:

```
jqGrid('sortGrid', colName, reload)
```

from [Wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods&s%5B%5D=sortgrid):

> Sorts the given colname and shows the appropriate sort icon. The same (without sorting icon) can be done using setGridParam({sortname:'myname'}).trigger('reloadGrid'). If the reload is set to true, the grid reloads with the current page and sortorder settings.

Comment: I've tried this in the past, but I've run into performance issues on large reports that I want to sort on multiple columns. I've found using the sortorder and sortname options when creating the jqgrid is more efficient, but now I'm running into this problem. I am trying to do some setup in the onSortCol event to prepare the sorting, but it won't execute on load even if there is a sort applied.